# Query SP2013 Managed metadata term store

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, managed-metadata, rest, term-store

I was wondering if it is possible to query the Term Store via the REST API or Javascript Client Object Model in SP2013.

I can't quite seem to work out the naming scheme for the REST API to discover end points.

eg:

```
/site/_api/web/...

/site/_api/site/..
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've recently written a post on how to access Term Store in SharePoint 2013 using the javascript `"SP.Taxonomy.js"`

Hope it helps you. http://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/accessing-taxonomy-term-store-with-jsom/

Answer (score 6):

JSOM or REST API = no. BUT you can use JavaScript to call the Taxonomy Web Service to effectively accomplish client-side access. It's definitely more cumbersome than using the CSOM or REST API, though, but it works.

Try this out:
http://spandps.com/tag/web-services/

The taxonomy picker with suggestions uses this web service client-side.

**UPDATE:** See the other answers. Sorry for the misinformation re: JSOM; I was thinking SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API does not support manipulating Taxonomy Items but they can be modified by using the JSOM.

http://www.vrdmn.com/2012/12/working-with-taxonomy-and-javascript-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Loading SharePoint TermStore is very easy. you have load default terms and then have to get the term store by name. and also you can get additional properties of the term store. you can get more details in this article. This Article may be helpful for you. Mark as answer if it is helpful info.

http://www.sharepointsol.com/2015/06/SharePoint-2013-JSOM-Get-Term-Store.html

Answer (score 0):

As a thumb rule..

Use REST APIs for list data operations, for rest of requirements better to use client side APIs.

REST APIs doesn't support Taxonomy retrieval/manipulations, please use client side APIs.