# SP2016: How can I display term set and its terms by Uniqe ID and using JavaScript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, javascript, term-store, term-set

In Term store management "Managed_Metadata_Service", I have "My TermSet" that have terms.

[image]

I want to display the terms from a term store and "My TermSet" by Unique Identifier and using Javascript Object Model. How can this be done?

Comment: Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78514/accessing-terms-in-term-store-using-jsom-in-sharepoint-2013/78947) and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136047/sharepoint-2013-get-all-taxonomy-terms-jsom) to access the terms store using JSOM. It may help you.

Comment: Thanks. I see them, and I tried. They are not work. I'm new to coding. Can I use these codes on a single page? And do they need some special calls to work?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to list terms in a term set of my default term store using following code.

```
var test = {};
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(spready, "sp.js");
function spready() {
var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "_layouts/15/";
$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", function () {

    var termID = "8ed8c9ea-7052-4c1d-a4d7-b9c10bffea6f";
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext);
    termStore = taxonomySession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();

    var termSet = termStore.getTermSet(termID);

    test.terms = termSet.get_terms();

    clientContext.load(taxonomySession);
    clientContext.load(termStore);
    clientContext.load(termSet);
    clientContext.load(test.terms);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onTermSucceeded, onTermFailed);

});

}

function onTermSucceeded(sender, args) {
console.log("term success:");
console.log(test.terms);


}

function onTermFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Termset Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

You may also take a reference of below blog:

- https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/accessing-taxonomy-term-store-with-jsom/
- https://github.com/msisgreat/js/blob/master/Taxonomy/termsetScript.js

BR

Comment: Thanks a lot.
When I using your code, alert me this error message: "Termset Error: Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null. "GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore
Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession".
Where do you think the problem comes from?