# HTML5/JavaScript Form with Complex Field Types

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs

I am developing a responsive Website on top of SharePoint using Angular and have a few list forms that I need to establish. For fields such as text and date via saving or updating against the REST API, it works well, but I am unsure how best to handle having Managed Metadata and other complex fields in my custom HTML5 form that Posts via REST.

To be clear, my end goal is to mimic form behavior using JavaScript (ex. creating Managed Metadata and Lookup fields)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can (yet, perhaps in SP 2016), see [Query SP2013 Managed metadata term store](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60045/query-sp2013-managed-metadata-term-store) - Use JSOM.

Since you use Angular I would suggest your wrap `SP.ClientContext` in a promise, this way you can use both JSOM and REST (`$http`) together fluently, like this:

Setup:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
ctx.exec = function() {
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(resolve, reject);
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
var web = ctx.get_web();
ctx.load(web);
ctx.exec().then(function() {
  console.log(web.get_title());
});
```